# NHibernate asking for LAST_INSERT_ID all the time?

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I have a simple object:

```
class Entity {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
}
```

If I insert 10 entities using the same transaction, I get the following calls:

```
INSERT INTO ...
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()

INSERT INTO ...
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()

...

INSERT INTO ...
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

I'm not using those entities anymore, just inserting them.

I saw that while using the logger to see the SQL generated when writing some complex query, and then I noticed it happens with the other tests too.

Is that the normal behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal if you have the primary key numbering strategy set to autoincrement. If you use a different strategy, like low-high or another algorithmic mechanism, it won't be necessary, because NHibernate can set the ID itself. There's a [blog post](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_RCGKpNU6R8TDuQykzRgrOa7rU1-NEFXEkketvpgdNQ/edit) on primary key strategies, which may not be up to date on all the available Id generation mechanisms, but has the main ones covered. There's some performance and related information about the different strategies you can choose [here](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/20/nhibernate-poid-generators-revealed.aspx). If memory serves me, using a sequence generator may be more performant on databases that support them, because Nhibernate can (at least theoretically) ask for them before using them.

For the mapping of your Id property to work as you'd expect, finding out what Id was just inserted is important. Also, for mapping any associations that depend on that primary key, the ORM needs to know the primary key of the root object, so you'll likely see a round of updates on any inserted association records. (This is also the reason why one side of the association should set the Inverse property).

Comment: The thing is... I thought it was only necessary when performing additional operations with that object, but not after every INSERT call. Does it mean that if I insert 200 objects, it will perform 200 `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` calls? I'm worried about performance...

Comment: If you're worried about performance of those "extra" selects, use a different primary key numbering strategy. NHibernate won't be able to guess when you might or might not ask what the recently persisted object's Id property is.

Comment: I was using a text field first (since that column must be unique), but NHibernate *checked* if any row had that ID before doing the insert (eg. `select * from entity where text = ..`). I thought it was supposed to insert the entity, and catch the exception from the db if an existing ID was there...

Comment: Anyway, I was just thinking if I broke something during the last build, but it looks like it was always happening...

Comment: Keep in mind that the primary key strategy is only _related_ to the type of the primary key (varchar, uuid, int/long, etc), it is not itself the type. There are hi/lo and identity (autoincrement) int/longs, for example, and there are string and byte strategies for UUID. You need to set the strategy in your mapping. (I don't think you can use a text field as a primary key in most DBMS systems I'm aware of, but you can use varchar/char/nvarchar.)

Comment: Yes, I meant `varchar`. One last question: Is it normal that NHibernates does `SELECT * FROM entity WHERE text = `123`` if I want to insert an entity with `Text` = `123`? (Text is the primary key, VARCHAR)

Comment: It probably depends on which strategy you're using. Did you map the primary key to Assigned?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40848/discussion-between-oscar-mederos-and-jasontrue)

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior if your key fields in your model mapping define the `Generators.Identity` generator.

If you inspect the `ID` field of the model you just persisted, it will now contain the actual database value.